# Creating instance of typeScript interface / generic

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

In the following example, an instance of EventEmitter interface is being created however, I believe that the interfaces can't be instantiated but the classes.

```
@Output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

---

Complete code below:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Output() sharedData: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>;

  shareData() {
    this.sharedData.emit('Hello, world!!!');
  }

}
```

Comment: Indeed, interfaces cannot be instantiated. But EventEmitter is a class, not an interface.

Comment: @kellermat actually VS CODE says it is interface when you hover mouse over it and it shows the tooltip:

(alias) interface EventEmitter<T>
import EventEmitter

Comment: I know what you mean and I'm a bit confused now too. My source was actually: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: When you write `new XXX` you are referring to a *value* named `XXX`, not a *type* named `XXX`, even though there might be such a type in scope.  So `EventEmitter` is presumably the name both of a constructor value and of an interface type.  This sort of thing happens automatically with `class` declarations (`class Foo {}` creates both a value named `Foo` and a type named `Foo`) but it can be done separately (like `interface Bar {}` and then `declare const Bar: new () => Bar`).

Comment: Could you [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue in a standalone IDE, including any `import` statements?  If you can do that that I could pinpoint exactly where the two definitions of `EventEmitter` are and why things behave as they behave.  Right now, though, all I have is that `EventEmitter` is not defined.  If you make such an edit and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your time. I have updated the question and put the complete code. It is simple nested component which is emitting an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows it is important to understand the difference in TypeScript between *types*, which only exist at compile time and are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when code is compiled to JavaScript; and *values*, which are emitted to JavaScript and therefore exist at runtime.  A value can have a type, but they are not the same thing and they exist in different syntactic contexts in TypeScript code.  In something like

```
const foo: Bar = baz<Qux>();
```

`Bar` and `Qux` are types and `foo` and `baz` are values.  When that code is compiled to JavaScript it will probably become

```
const foo = baz();
```

Because they exist in different syntactic contexts, you can actually have types and values use the same names without colliding with each other.  So you could have:

```
const A: B = B<A>();
```

where the first `B` and the second `A` are types, and the first `A` and the second `B` are values.  There is no necessary relationship between the value named `A` and the type named `A`.  The code above is exactly analogous to `const foo: Bar = baz<Qux>();`, things are just renamed.  This might be confusing to a human being but the compiler is not confused and knows from syntax context which ones are the values and which ones are the types.  The above would compile to

```
const A = B();
```

where the values remain and the types are gone.

---

For your example code the relevant definitions are located in Angular's [`event_emitter.ts`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/27da7338ea8f3bf5336d77ed1877cfa6a1974d52/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts).  If you hover over the imported `EventEmitter` in an IntelliSense-enabled IDE like
[The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAaOAUQDccZCRgYYsoCB5AVxjGbgF84AzKNOAcgACAQwwBzRgBthUAPQBjaFn4BuALAAoTYNTpsuABQJNcU3ADOWSVnkxoALgHCwYALTyAFsEkATfnhMzGnBpGgBVKElHfgA6BS9fGMU9MhiPGBBJf0DTcxgAT2tzRwBtHLgAXU12AEpNLAAPSFg4eWlzcxQEn11IfXhjLQ0zOEEmFmYDGosPGSwfABFhGGFHEjIKKhooAB48qGBxAD44AF44bAB3IlJcTepaPZgD4-UhkfNZqCwllanEcojGBecwxT5zRbLYQxLCUGAGfgACSskggBEu0F8AEIcfwam8RuxNNViRpZAAqOCaAzCSTAYTmaaHbZcYTyLA3DZw7Y7AAqJ1ksjgO1crjgwOAnUl4o8HIKYA51Np9MZrUweU5d25tEcSEFwtFMul0uBHOItMYWHKVzgBklAEFzPkMPIAPyOABGEAg1lEcAAPnBGBgfFguId5jU1rdyNrdqJ8kcCWYbXyjnbzI7nW7Pd7fRgA0GQ2GIz4o5rY1tHvzk6ZvsIfJhJPk4GBeHZ5Vho1yq-GMIm3kSNOTZEA), you should see something like this:

```
/* 
(alias) interface EventEmitter<T> 
(alias) const EventEmitter: { 
    new (isAsync?: boolean | undefined): EventEmitter<any>;
    new <T>(isAsync?: boolean | undefined): EventEmitter<T>;
    readonly prototype: EventEmitter<any>;
}
*/
```

That means there are two separate things named `EventEmitter`. The first is `interface EventEmitter<T>`, a named [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *type*.  If this were the only declaration of `EventEmitter` then you would not be able to instantiate it.  The second is `const EventEmitter`, a named *value*, the type of which hose type contains some [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), one of which is generic.  If you call the generic construct signature, then the returned value is of type `EventEmitter<T>`;

So in the line

```
@Output() sharedData: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>;
//                      ^                                  ^
// (alias) interface EventEmitter<T>                       |
// (alias) new EventEmitter<string>(isAsync?: boolean | undefined): EventEmitter<string>
```

the first `EventEmitter<string>` is a generic interface type instantiated with `string`, while the latter `EventEmitter<string>` is part of a call to a generic constructor function.

---

Note that when you have a [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declaration, it introduces both a named type (the class instance type) and a named value (the class constructor value) with the same name.  This is useful, but it does give the erroneous impression that types and values that share names are inherently related to each other.

Anyway, a `class` declaration's named value and type relationship is essentially the same as the relationship with Angular's `EventEmitter`.  Indeed, they could have provided essentially the same typings with something like:

```
declare class EventEmitter<T = any> {
    constructor(isAsync?: boolean | undefined);
    new(isAsync?: boolean): EventEmitter<T>;
    emit(value?: T): void;
    subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void):
        Subscription;
    subscribe(observerOrNext?: any, error?: any, complete?: any): Subscription;
}
```

And then the code like

```
const xxx: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>;
//           ^                               ^
//        class EventEmitter<T = any>        |
// constructor EventEmitter<string>(isAsync?: boolean | undefined): EventEmitter<string>
```

would do the same thing except that IntelliSense would use `class` and `constructor` to refer to the type and value instead of `interface` and `new`.

You could then ask, if those are the same, why didn't they use a `class` declaration instead of an `interface`/`const` pair?  That's a good question but probably out of scope here.  In general there are things you can't adequately describe with a `class` declaration and in those cases a type/value pair would be necessary, so perhaps this was done to give the most flexibility.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAaOAUQDccZCRgYYsoCB5AVxjGbgF84AzKNOAcgACAQwwBzRgBthUAPQBjaFn4BuALAAoTYNTpsuABQJNcU3ADOWSVnkxoALgHCwYALTyAFsEkATfnhMzGnBpGgBVKElHfgA6BS9fGMU9MhiPGBBJf0DTcxgAT2tzRwBtHLgAXU12AEpNLAAPSFg4eWlzcxQEn11IfXhjLQ0zOEEmFmYDGosPGSwfABFhGGFHEjIKKhooAB48qGBxAD44AF44bAB3IlJcTepaPZgD4-Vhs1lZEe+f34A9X6AoHAv7lT5wAzCSTAYTmaaHbZcYTyLA3DaUB67AAqJ2BeLgAB8wV9IdDYdMrmi7hjtk8XmIjgZgOYAILmfIYeQAfkcACMIBBrKJCXBGBgfFguId5jU1rdyDTHvtDgzNOVzLMoFglispohyiMYF5zDENXNFsthDEsBiDPwABJWSQQAiXaC+ACEXv4NTeI3Yao0AaGsgAVHBNKSYXC4AjaEiUVSFVtHji4OCdq5XHAjczY50jaiCmBUZGodHpooMHkk-dto4kBmsznjfmW6jiFDGFhypSmaz2ZyeXB+YKsMKCaLxZLpT5ZbXFbtRPkjn6zJSdjj+2yOdy+QKhRgRWKJVLsHO5eiU9jV+UtcIfJhJPk4GBeHZi1hL9Trztl7eg00UNZEDDBhBALBzDAZFUQAWWEfJeVRQYRjjKAE1RABlRheXMeQDjAGBgEwRAOHKCU2jmVp2k6dYf0xTczjgf99XeH4q32RhbGgbdBz3EcD3HI9JxPGdz19A11ywS5eN3YdR0Pec6OTBicTXH4bSoAxO0kbthyxediAgYAfHU75zBwvCDiQgxsAaGBh20rsvzgAyzhOIyTIIWheCgRyfIcZiMHyaZTg84yfAIZIwGsGhHNC8KTNlSSfmw3D8OAQjiIwMyRgs9LrKwAwIFw2hSCgegoAAOUaBzHGXbyoF84cGtaNAYqwOL6uC+c0qszKiMwMzgxGDj4DNLULRob8VNpZVjiYyllLrJVnhVACRnBSiOgXX8sSY-9iTa6tni4uwoF2hj5oZWSh33McJynU9ZyU+UVt2a6jmqIA)